# random shortest grid walk

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables

Let $W$ be a random shortest grid walk from $(0,0) \to (20,20)$. Compute exactly

a) the expected area above or to the left of $W$,

b) the expected number of turns of $W$.

Please help, give some hints!

Comment: Use linearity of expectation.  For part (a) try looking at the expected sum of the area above the curve plus the area below the curve.  For part (b) consider the probability that you have a turn after $k$ steps, this won't depend on $k$, the expectation is just this probability times the number of potential times you could turn.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for B: you might try to look the star and bars theorem. If you write the paths like $x^{p_1}y^{p_2}\ldots z^{p_{i+1}}$(x is to go up and y to go right) where z is x or y depending in the parity of i, you would have i changes of direction. So you are interested in how many ways you can write 20 as sum of $p_1+p_3+\ldots+p_{2k+1}+\ldots p_{t}$ and $p_2+p_4+\ldots+p_{2k}+\ldots p_{t'}$ where t and t' ara i or i+1 depending in the parity of i such that $p_j\geq 1$ for every j.

Answer (score -1):

You are in Pak's course right?

Consider 11 positions between Rs, each Up take place will have 0, 1, 2...10 added area.

Comment: the second part, using same thought: any position between Rs create 2 turns except the beginning and the end; and put Us randomly, see what happen